# What's is the maximum variables the sql "in" statement can handle

Tags: sql, database, mysql5

As said above
For instance WHERE In(var 1,var 2,var 3, ..., var 5609,)

Any limits before it slows the machine down ?

Comment: Which SQL database server are you using? No doubt it varies between each implementation.

Comment: MySQL 5.1.36  Cheers for the help buddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a limit to the number of values in the list of the IN clause in MySQL, unlike the 1000 Oracle limit.  I would verify this though by writing some sort of loop to build a really long 'IN' statement if you had a concern.   Also, [someone else asked this question and there wasn't a known limit.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532366/mysql-number-of-items-within-in-clause)

Answer (score 3):

I would say that if you have to ask then you're probably doing something wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle 9i [Maximum number of expressions](http://download-east.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e1500.htm#1001274) in a list is 1000;

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle (Verified only in 10g) it is 1000.

`ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000`

Answer (score 0):

With "limits", are you referring to a limitation in the the implementation, or something that will slow the query down? If it's the latter, the best answer is test it yourself.

Comment: Sorry for being vague. I am just asking if a few thousand numbers inside the in statement is too much and will bring the server to a halt 
:)

Comment: You could possibly try inserting that data into a temp table first.

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL Server chokes at around 2000, MS SQL Compact has no limits (or I have not reached it yet, more than 2500).

Note: these are limits on parameters for queries.