# MySQL IN condition limit

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

Hey, I have to use IN condition in my MySQL statement with a large set of ids.

Example

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4...100000)
```

Is there a limit if items the IN statement can have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL number of items within "in clause"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532366/mysql-number-of-items-within-in-clause)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

No there isn't, check the [manual about the IN function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in):

> The number of values in the `IN` list is only limited by the [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) value.

Comment: so if I have, for example, an update with `where id IN (14000 ids)`, it will work until update query is less than 64MB (which is the default value), right?

Comment: @OlegAbrazhaev The `IN` keyword does not have any build-in limits, however there might be other limits like `max_allowed_packet` which might indirect limit the number of values. If you set this value to 1024 (bytes) you can effectively use only a limited number of values.

Comment: @Progman do you have a source for the indirect limiting of the query values?

Comment: @VinShahrdar The quote in the answer is from the official MySQL manual.

Comment: I understand that, but the official manual doesn't have any details about what happens when you go over the max_allowed_packet limit. I was troubleshooting a similar issue, where a query uses an IN operator with a ton of values in it (more than 100,000) and I was noticing some of the expected items aren't coming back, which led me to this thread!

Comment: @VinShahrdar When you hit the limit you get an error message like `ERROR 1153 (08S01): Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes`. So it looks like the query will fail completely in that case. As your queries succeeds (but return unexpected rows) the issue might not be the `max_allowed_packet` setting.

Comment: @Progman so we truncated that table that was causing the IN operator in the query to have more than 100,000 elements (which were mostly duplicates). After that, with only 500 records in the IN operator, the query returns the expected items. That's pretty crazy!

Answer (score 25):

As far as I know in mysql, there is no limit for items in the `IN` statement.

In oracle altough, there is a limit of 1000 items in the `IN` statement.

But more the items in `IN`, your query performance will slow down unless that column is indexed.

Comment: depends, if the IN is search primary key, is fast cause is return from index

Comment: For comparison, SQLServer (MSSQL) has a limitation of around 2100 parameters in the total query, including in parameters.  
Postgres has no limit.  
SQLite has no limit.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

1073741824 This is the limit given in Mysql docs

Comment: thank you for sharing this, I guess one major reason this is downvoted is because it does not explain that the quantity of elements within the IN condition of the querry is not directly limited , but indirectly by the overall querry size which this config parameter is for. Anyway I find it usefull to find the default setting here, thank you