# Limit of IN clause in JPA

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an update query in JPA/ Hibernate like this:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "UPDATE dogs d " +
        "SET d.active = 0 " +
        "WHERE d.id IN (:dogIds) AND d.active = 1",
        nativeQuery = true)
void softDeleteDogs(List<Long> dogIds);
```

I was wondering if having a large number of items in the `dogIds` list will cause an issue in MySQL when executing a query (and thus, maybe I would need to paginate that list instead). Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I know there is no limit in JPA, but there is definitely a limit in underlying databases. You can use either batching (split single query into multiple queries with smaller `IN` chunks) or you can use temporary tables - insert whole list of ids in such table and then rewrite your original UPDATE query so that instead of IN clause it would use the join with that temporary table.

Comment: you can also read this excellent answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52363760/2224047

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL IN clause: max number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666502/mysql-in-clause-max-number-of-arguments)

Comment: Yes, pretty much.