# Match large (over 2K) CSV ID list not in my DB with ID fields on my DB using WHERE IN

Tags: mysql

I'm gonna need to match several ID's that aren't on my DB with ID values that are in my DB, something like:

```
SELECT ... WHERE idfield IN (123454, 12312312, 1223123, 12313123 ...., 99923412)
```

Can WHERE IN hold this many strings for matching? Sometimes I'm gonna match something like 200 IDs, other times, 600, as max as 2000 IDs.

Is there a better way to do it? Im really worried about memory and speed.

**EDIT**: Ok, one of my questions was answered, there are no limits to the WHERE IN and the query will be faster if the field I'm matching with is indexed. ([MySQL IN condition limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275640/mysql-in-condition-limit))

But, I'm also looking for alternatives here, so if anyone have another technique on this match function, that would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275640/mysql-in-condition-limit - although one wonders why you're comparing a string of integers instead of using a simple join from somewhere.

Comment: @Strawberry I don't have the integer group CSV on my DB for matching. I'm taking this outside 200 id lists in CSV format and I must match with a column on my DB that may/may not have a match with this CSV

Comment: Load ID values from CSV file into another table, then write a SELECT query to find differences.

Comment: @Devart is it faster to insert 2k ids in another table and write a JOIN than it is to compare using this CSV with a WHERE IN? Any references on this?

Comment: 2k - is it a lot? No. About SELECT+JOIN - ID fields have to be indexed.