# MySQL bulk update, update flags of registered, unregistered users

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

My current table has users a, b, c, d, e, f registered.

Then I get a full list of all registered users and it lists c, d, e, f, g h.

This means a, b have unregistered, and g, h are new registering users.

Note*: There is no event that tells me when a users registers or unregisters. Only a list of all registered users, that I don't want to access more than once a day.

My current method of updating the MySQL:

```
UPDATE users SET registered = -1 WHERE registered = 1;
```

Then I proceed to update the table with my new list of all registered users:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, registered) VALUES($userid[i], 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE registered = 1;
```

Then I proceed to update the table flagging users who have unregistered:

```
UPDATE users SET registered = 0, unregistered = 1 WHERE registered = -1;
```

Basically using -1 as indicator that a user was registered but not anymore according to the full list;

This works fine with a small table, but takes hours with tens of thousands.

Is there a better way?

Reducing it to a few minutes would be more than acceptable.

Comment: Why are you doing all this, surely it should all be part of a user registering, or unregistering

Comment: I think you are too quick to down vote the question. The project is of the web scraping sort. There is no event that tells me when a users registers or un-registers. Only a list of all registered users, that I don't want to access more than once a day.

Comment: Actually I did not downvote the question :)

Comment: Ah, maybe the key part of the 'algorithm' is "not more than once a day"?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `where in` like so

```
UPDATE users set registered = 1 WHERE id in (implode($userid,','))
```

you implode the users ids

the sql statement should look like this

```
UPDATE users set registered = 1 WHERE id in (1,2,3,5)
```

Edit: here is a link to mysql batch insert
[How to do a batch insert in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526917/how-to-do-a-batch-insert-in-mysql)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm assuming this should be done in multiple queries with say 200 ids at a time? How many ids do you recommend per query, since the full registration list can be 100,000

Comment: technically it's not limited you can do it for more elaborate answers check this link,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275640/mysql-in-condition-limit

and this one

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532366/mysql-number-of-items-within-in-clause

Comment: Is this going to speed up the processing?

Comment: I've updated the question. The update process also includes insertion of users not listed in the table. UPDATE WHERE IN would fail to add these users.

Comment: well if you loop and run the update for each user in php it would be slow as hell,
a lot slower than doing it in a query in the database, in general do database stuff in database

Comment: this might help 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526917/how-to-do-a-batch-insert-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

The secret is to throw out the nasty `UPDATE`.

Instead of `registered` column being some sort of flag, make it a `DATETIME`.

Now the test is on `WHERE ts < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY` -- There is no need to change `registered` daily!

When you act on one of the items, simply update it with `UPDATE ... ts = NOW() WHERE id = ...`.

Comment: ah, using a last_date_seen_registered. anyone who hasnt been on a recent list is known to have unregistered. yes!