# Maximum Limit For IN Query in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know how many maximum items you can query on in mysql Query with "IN" clause.
For eg:
select * from student where student.name IN ("a1","a2","a3", ..... "an");

Comment: You can refer here. There is no limit to it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4275704/10342514

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of values in IN clause is defined  by the max_allowed_packet value.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet

> Default Value (>= 8.0.3)   67108864
>    Default Value (<=
>   8.0.2)    4194304

But if your IN result can be generated  by a query then you could replace the IN clause with an INNER JOIN

Comment: I think this is a better answer than the so-called duplicate.