# How many values in an "in" clause is too many in a SQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL query that uses the values of an array in its WHERE clause:

```
 $ids = array 
         ( 
           [0] => 1 
           [1] => 2 
           [2] => 5 
         ) 

 $ids = join(',',$ids);   
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM cats WHERE id IN ($ids)";
```

My question is how many ids are too many?
Will it effect the speed?

Thanks all

Comment: It all depends on your table structure and indexes. And obviously as Sergei stated the more the slower.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL number of items within "in clause"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532366/mysql-number-of-items-within-in-clause)

Answer (score 7):

Oracle has a limit of 1000, which I've hit before. MySQL doesn't seem to mind. The best solution is not to use an IN clause for that large a dataset though. Where do the ids come from? If from the same DB, then see if you can use a subquery instead that searches based on one parameter e.g. userid to find the linked ids. This will be far more efficient as MySQL can do a join internally using indexes.

Comment: What if the ids do not come from the same DB? Example: a set of ids is received from a different database, possibly from a NoSQL database or other API?

Answer (score 6):

The more data you select, the longer this takes, but your primary concern should not be the number of ids you SELECT. Instead, you should ensure that your id has an `INDEX` on it or that it is the `PRIMARY KEY`. This will make lookups fast no matter how many ids you're grabbing.

Comment: Generally yes. But if you combine `IN` with `ORDER` and `LIMIT`, you get problems on large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

think of..if you have to write 5 pages or 10 what takes longer...it's normal if you have a huge amount of ids to take the query longer.You should look and assure that your data is not repeating because that will make the query take longer for unnecessary data..

Answer (score -1):

The more values you put into `IN`, the slower it will run, obviously.

"how many is too many" is a function of many factors. For example, your dataset size. Or how the rest of your query looks like.