# Specified method is not supported MySql Entity Framwork 6

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to run the following Linq query from `MySQL` client

```
    query = query.Where(c => c.CustomerRoles
                              .Select(cr => cr.Id)
                              .Intersect(customerRoleIds)
                              .Any()
                       );
```

This code looks okay, but gives the error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.at MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.Visit(DbIntersectExpression expression)
```

This looks to me like an issue with .Intersect. Can anybody tell me the cause of this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think @GertArnold's post is a correct and best of the answers, but i'm wonder why have you gotten `NotSupportedException` yet ? so the problem should not be from `intersect` probably.

where is `customerRoleIds` come from ? is it `IQueryable<T>` ?

break the query, and complete it step by step.

if you don't get exception at this lines:

```
var a = query.Select(c => new { 
        c, 
        CustomerRoleIDList = c.CustomerRoles.Select(cr => cr.Id).AsEnumerable()
    })
    .ToList();

var b = customerRoleIds.ToList();
```

you must get the result by this:

```
var b = query.Where(c => c.CustomerRoles.any(u => customerRoleIds.Contains(u.Id)))
    .ToList();
```

if you get exception by above query, you can try this final solution to fetch data first, but note by this, all data will be fetched in memory first:

```
var a = query.Select(c => new { 
        c, 
        CustomerRoleIDList = c.CustomerRoles.Select(cr => cr.Id).AsEnumerable() 
    })
    .ToList();

var b = a.Where(c => c.CustomerRoleIDList.any(u => customerRoleIds.Contains(u)))
    .Select(u => u.c)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I think `Intersect` is not supported, hence the `NotSupportedException`. But I can't find any documentation of supported LINQ methods.

Comment: all function which your provide can translate to `expression tree` will be supported in linq, some functions which is called `canonical functions` is supported by default by all providers, you can read about this functions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738626(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: i think probably the problem is from `intersect` too, but you told, got same error when you done GertArnold's solution, and his solution was without `intersect` !!!

Comment: `Intersect` is a set function, not a canonical SQL function. Each provider can choose whether and how to support it. The same goes for `Any`. It's sad when a provider doesn't offer clear documentation on this part.

Comment: @GertArnold yes, you right, i posted canonical function documentation link for more information

Answer (score 2):

Using `Intersect` or `Except` is probably always troublesome with LINQ to a SQL backend. With Sql Server they may produce horrible SQL queries.

Usually there is support for `Contains` because that easily translates to a SQL `IN` statement. Your query can be rewritten as

```
query = query.Where(c => c.CustomerRoles
                 .Any(cr => customerRoleIds.Contains(cr.Id)));
```

I don't think that `customerRoleIds` will contain many items (typically there won't be hundreds of roles), otherwise you should take care not to hit the [maximum number of items allowed in an `IN` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1532366/861716).

Comment: Which version of, I guess, dotConnect are you using?

Comment: mysql connector 6.8.3

Comment: Is `Any` not supported by connector?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding toList() before intersect, that should enumerate results locally instead running on MySql, you will get performance hit thought.

```
 query = query.Where(c => c.CustomerRoles.Select(cr => cr.Id)).ToList().Intersect(customerRoleIds);
```

Comment: still giving the Same error, while filtering other fields , when trying to inspect the "Query" object its showing the My Sql Query in it, but when this (Intersect) statement is Run, its showing that "Query" as object.

Comment: your customerRoleIds are enumerated right? if not toList() them too.

Comment: @fez I have made an edit try that instead and please let me know how it goes.

Comment: Now giving syntax Error:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'bool'

Comment: Remove .Any() at the end

Comment: giving error here:c.CustomerRoles.Select(cr => cr.Id)) not on Any()

Comment: So the problem is not with .Intersect() I presume, as logic now does the following - SelectIds and make them into list = SELECT Id FROM [TableName], there must be some other underlying problem. Could you just to confirm run this var x = query.Where(c => c.CustomerRoles.Select(cr => cr.Id));

Comment: giving same error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'bool'

Comment: sorry my bad try this var x = query.SelectMany(c => c.CustomerRoles.Select(cr => cr.Id));

Answer (score 1):

```
query.Where(c => c.CustomerRoles
                 .Any(v=>customerRoleIds.Any(e=>e == v.Id))
     .Select(cr => cr.Id))
     .ToList();
```

Comment: giving syntax error :bool does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extention method