# Is it possible to UPDATE with WHERE 'FIELD' IN clause? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

We have this in a table:

**TABLE A**

```
ID      DAY   CALL
mdma     1     A
mdma2    2     B
mdma3    3     C
```

So I want to update all fields CALL based in their ID.

```
UPDATE A SET CALL = 'D' WHERE ID IN ('mdma','mdma2', 'mdma3');
```

I'm getting errors on DataStudio, and I cannot run it. And we have a debate with this WHERE IN clause. Is this a valid argument or not?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

```
ERROR:

An unexpected token ")" was found following "mdma', 
".  Expected tokens may include:  "<value_expr>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.16.53
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Can you show us the error?

Comment: yes, it's valid sql. what's the specific error?

Comment: And that is the actual statement? it seems like you are missing a quote, maybe the query is inside some varible using single quotes?

Comment: CALL is a reserved word. Needs backticks around it. There might be other problems.

Comment: I will check again, the thing is the current query is having like 50K records. Seems pretty obvious to me, but is just giving me headaches.

Comment: How is an update statement with a syntax error giving you 50K records?

Comment: @axor When you say your current query has 50k records, are you saying that the table you're updating has 50k records, or you have a `IN` statement with 50k entries?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' It was just an example table/fields. Thanks for the note.

Comment: @axor please show us the real statement and if you can, in the context, this is a sintax error, pretty sure some missing/extra quote

Comment: @axor We can't figure out what the problem might be if you're only giving us an example query that is neither using the same table/fields nor generating an error.

Comment: @Siyual UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = 'X' WHERE ID IN (<50K IDs>);

Comment: Yeah, no.  Don't do that.  Put them in a temp table and join to it or something.  Even if it didn't fuss about a missing quote, you would still get an error about having too many conditions in the `IN` clause.  And even if for some reason it didn't, performance would be murder...

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de7ef4/1/0 it works.  however there is a limit of sorts on the size of the in clause (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532366/mysql-number-of-items-within-in-clause)

Comment: 50k of an alphanumeric id isn't a good idea. Use chunks, a temp table or something. In that 50k you can fail a quote or your software is limiting the long of the string or a lot of other possible problems.
By the way, there must be a reason to use a string like ID, but in a table with 50k+ rows, i strongly recommend you to use a numeric id.

Comment: The error message doesn't really sound like MySQL. Are you sure you are using that?

Answer (score 0):

CALL is reserved word. you must quote it with backtick (“`”):

```
UPDATE A SET `CALL` = 'D' WHERE ID IN ('mdma','mdma2', 'mdma3');
```

Comment: In the comments OP said it was just an example. Good call BTW

Comment: This is only a minor part of the issue (which is not clear from the question, but is made clear in the comments to it - the OP is trying to use 50,000+ IDs in the `IN` statement).