# Is there a limit on the number of rows I can update via an IN clause of a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

Is there a limit on the number of rows that I can update in a single query using an `IN` clause? For example:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `row`=1 WHERE `id` IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8....5000)");
```

Could I update all 5000 rows at once? Or does MySQL have a limit on the number of items in an `IN` clause?

**Please note:** I want to know if there is a limit of updates in one single query where MySQL would say something like *"maximum number of IN clause entries exceeded"*. That is, I am inquiring about a possible limit ***other than*** the "maximum packet size" setting in MySQL.

Comment: From my personnal experience, when you have doubts on how many elements will be in the list IN (either 100 or 1 million), it is better to split the list in chunks.

Comment: if the numbers are consistent use WHERE id <5000 or use a table to store those numbers and JOIN on that

Comment: I've seen 70K items; it was slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [MySQL documentation for the IN function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in), there is no *hard limit* on the number of values that can be specified in such a list. The documentation specifically says:

> The number of values in the IN list is only limited by the max_allowed_packet value.

However, there is another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1532366/2144390) that discusses whether or not there might be a *practical limit* beyond which a temporary table containing the values might yield better performance when used with a `JOIN` or an `IN(subquery)` in the `WHERE` clause.