# How many rows MySql can update using "IN" clause in a single query

Tags: mysql

I was wandering what's the limit for a query to update a good number of fields in a single table using an "IN" clause.

I'm talking about a range between a 5,000 to 2,000,000 rows in each call.

Is this something I should be concern about?

The sample query can be something like:

```
UPDATE table_name SET
    field1 = '',
    field2 = '',
    field3 = '',
    field4 = '',
    field5 = '',
    field6 = '',
    field7 = ''
WHERE id IN (
    1,
    2,
    3,
    ...,
    999998,
    999999,
    1000000
)
```

Comment: There's no right answer for this question; it depends on too many things. Just test it out and see where it breaks.

Comment: Thanks @mike32, any chance you could mentioned a few of those many things it depends on? this will be a great help to me to get better understand about potential disadvantages of such approach.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8808935/4949388

Comment: Thanks @JonathanParentLévesque, it was really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitation on number of records to upddate by any condition clause, including **IN** on the mysqlside, however there are platform and performance related stuff which you might want to concider. have a look at [How to update 10 million+ rows in MySQL single table as Fast as possible?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119621/how-to-update-10-million-rows-in-mysql-single-table-as-fast-as-possible)