# Filter rows with several large vectors

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table A with several columns:

```
 A              B              C
 1              2              7  
 1              2              8 
 2              2              1 
 1              3              1
```

I have to build a function in Java which takes 3 vectors as input, vA, vB, vC and returns the rows that have any of the values in the vectors. The arrays works as a filter. `A = {1,2,3,4}, b = {2}, C={7}` would return a row but `A = {1}, b = {2}, C={0}` would not since no row in column c has value 0

- The vectors are so large so it is not possible to generate a lot of OR's like `WHERE (c = ? OR c = ? ...c = ? )`
- It has to be safe from SQL-injection
- Performance is essential

Other threads(https://stackoverflow.com/a/1532454/1991779), suggestions a temporary table and then joining the tables. The problem is that I have several vectors to match several columns with and not one. I think I could create a table, insert all values and then use

```
 WHERE A IN (SELECT A FROM TEMP ) AND B IN (SELECT B FROM TEMP ) AND  C
 IN (SELECT C FROM TEMP )
```

However, I think It would be much faster to use `JOIN` instead of `IN`. Any suggestions to do it with `Join` instead of `IN`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where exists perhaps as engine can stop looking on first occurrence.

Comment: In is just a shorthand for creating a bunch of OR statements (with maybe a small performance boost, but I haven't experienced that).  If you want to use joins, you could dump the values you want to match into a temp table, and then join your table to that temp table on the relevant field.

Comment: How should I insert the values in a tmp table? It can't be one value per row, right? The only way would be to do all permutations, otherwise, the join would miss some valid cases? Is that correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the concept of a `cross join` a.k.a. Cartesian Product (all permutations). So your arrays produce a derived table (in memory) with a row count of `x*y*z`, where those x,y,z are the sizes of the arrays. If you supplied arrays of size 3,4, and 5, the derived table would have a row count of 3*4*5=60.

Your supplied array matchup that produces a row was only 4*1*1=4

`thing7` below is your main table you are searching. The `covering index` should make this thing fly even with a ton of data in it. A covering index is one in which the information provided is given via the b-tree scan of the index, and that a data page read is not required. Why? Because the data needed is in the index. And in your case, extremely thin.

Tables A B C are for use as your arrays.

The only other thing to say is that every derived table requires a name. So we gave it the name `xDerived` in the query. Think of a derived table as something returned and used in memory. It is not a physical table.

### Schema

```
create table thing7
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    A int not null,
    B int not null,
    C int not null,
    index(A,B,C) -- covering index (uber-thin, uber-fast)
);

insert thing7(A,B,C) values
(1,2,7),  
(1,2,8), 
(2,2,1), 
(1,3,1);

create table A
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    value int
);
create table B
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    value int
);
create table C
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    value int
);
```

### Test 1

```
truncate table A;
truncate table B;
truncate table C;
insert A (value) values (1),(2),(3),(4);
insert B (value) values (2);
insert C (value) values (7);

select t7.* 
from thing7 t7  
join 
(   select A.value as Avalue, B.value as Bvalue, C.value as Cvalue 
    from A 
    cross join B 
    cross join C 
    order by a.value,b.value,c.value 
) xDerived 
on xDerived.Avalue=t7.A and xDerived.Bvalue=t7.B and xDerived.Cvalue=t7.C; 
+----+---+---+---+
| id | A | B | C |
+----+---+---+---+
|  1 | 1 | 2 | 7 |
+----+---+---+---+
```

..

### Test 2

```
truncate table A;
truncate table B;
truncate table C;
insert A (value) values (1);
insert B (value) values (2);
insert C (value) values (0);

select t7.*
from thing7 t7 
join
(   select A.value as Avalue, B.value as Bvalue, C.value as Cvalue
    from A
    cross join B
    cross join C
    order by a.value,b.value,c.value
) xDerived
on xDerived.Avalue=t7.A and xDerived.Bvalue=t7.B and xDerived.Cvalue=t7.C;
-- no rows returned
```

It would be very easy to turn this into a session-based search. The concept there is one in which the arrays to search (tables A B C) have a session column. It would then facilitate multi-user concurrent use. But that is over-engineering the answer but ask if you want more info on that.

Comment: To make it session-based, do "create temporary table" when creating the tables.

Does the ordering makes a performance difference?

Comment: To me a temporary table should not be used for these types of things if performance is key. That is due to the overhead of DDL commands.That is easily testable. For instance, I noticed a significant improvement in a call once that I showed here on the Stack with using versus not using a temp table. In the case of not, it would use a normal non-temp table and utilize a session concept. Your session/mysession. The ways it would make a session would be thru an auto_inc value retrieved from a control table. Therefore we are each safely segmented from each other (high concurrency systems)

Comment: But testing will bring that out into the light of day for which is appropriate for you, and what performance is required. As for your question of does ordering make a difference, I can't see that making much of a difference because the `thing7` table already has the best setup with a `covering index` and at the moment your A B C are so small that indexes aren't ever used on small tables (even if you have those indexes in place). They are simply skipped. I could point you to a manual page that definitively answers why they are skipped.

Comment: Could you please evaluate about how I can use a a non temporary table and still perform session-based search.

Comment: What do you mean evaluate? I just mentioned how one would do it above. I think what you ought to do is implement this code and evaluate how you like it.