# How a mysql query works on the basis of information schema

Tags: mysql, select, information-schema

I was trying to solve one MySQL query at [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com), which demands to draw following pattern:

```
* * * * * 
* * * * 
* * * 
* * 
*
```

and in discussions, I found below mysql query, which is fetching data from `information_schema` to draw the required pattern, which I couldn't understand.

```
SELECT REPEAT('* ', @NUMBER := @NUMBER - 1) FROM information_schema.tables, (SELECT @NUMBER:=6) t LIMIT 5
```

Can anyone please explain the flow of this query, how exactly it is working?

Comment: It is just using a table that should have enough rows for the iteration.  Rather obscure, if you are not used to this sort of thing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Thank you for your reply. I understand, it is using table to have enough rows. But can you please explain, how it is making sure to fetch the table from information schema, about which one is not sure to have enough rows. It would be kind of you, if you can elaborate it bit more.

Comment: . . Personally, I think `columns` would be a much better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it works is that info schema dot tables has probably hundreds of rows in it for you.

You can verify that. It merely wanted some source that has more than 5 rows. It could have been anything.

It does a cross join to just initialize a variable (`@NUMBER`) to the number 6. It brings back the repeat starting at 5 asteriks, 1 less per time, for a limit of 5 rows.

Comment: Are these entries coming from temporary table of information schema? I couldn't find enough reference for the insertion of the entries in these tables. I also tried to execute this query in my local setup, and got 283 records in total. But from where these records are actually generated? Can you please throw some light on this?

Comment: There are like 3 dozen tables in the specialty info schema database. They are auto maintained by the server as structures and relations and all else that they hold, change. Your asterisks query has 2 tables in it. The first is a table that has 283 rows (mine has 311 or so). The second table is a derived table with 1 row and 1 column. It is the number 6. So for you, you have the potential of running thru that 283 times if the `LIMIT 5` wasnt tacked on.

Comment: You need to remember that this is just a Cartesian Product of MxN, where M=283 and N=1. But the LIMIT 5 reduces it to 5. This question basically has nothing to do with [INFO SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html) which was only used as a dummy input to start generating the asterisks

Comment: Thanks Drew. It helped a lot.

Comment: It is somewhat related to this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37929532). Note that an inner join or a cross join are very similar and effectively the same thing when bringing in a variable. When you are *not* bringing in a variable, a cross join in what we think of normally as a Cartesian Product (all permutations)

Comment: Someone should probably also mention that leveraging `information_schema.tables` for disreputable purposes like this will get your database privileges revoked in a hurry if your DBA is paying attention.  The `tables` table in information_schema is particularly expensive to query in terms of server resources... perhaps the most resource-intensive one there is.  These "tables" are not "real" tables -- they're emulated tables that expose internal server data strictures through the SQL interface.  **Kids, don't try this at home.**

Comment: Yeah, it is probably a very reckless attempt to guarantee something to hit against. Good point @Michael-sqlbot

Answer (score -1):

information_schema can be used to draw patterns in mySQL.

SELECT REPEAT('* ', @NUMBER := @NUMBER - 1) FROM information_schema.tables, (SELECT @NUMBER:=6) t LIMIT 5;

This is the code with repeat function used to repeat the values

Comment: Please do not duplicate existing answers. `information_schema`  itself can not draw patterns