# Is there a nesting limit for `and` `or` in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the code that will help you understand my question:

```
select * 
from table1
where ((((field1=value1 and field2=value2) or field3=value3) and field4=value4) or field5=value5) ...
```

The `Parse Tree` are composed of `and` `or`. Is there a nesting limit for `Parse Tree`  in MySQL?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532366/mysql-number-of-items-within-in-clause

Comment: If there be a limit my guess is that you won't hit it, at least not querying a single table.  If you really have that many columns in a single table, then you have another probably bigger design problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  1. There are not so many columns. Like this: `where (field1=v1_1 or (field1=v1_2 and field2=v2_1 and(field1=v1_3 and field3=v3_1)) )`
2. It is used for `Data Analysis`. The query conditions is defined by user so I need nesting limit.