# Using multiple parameters in WHERE

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a list of ints called idList. I'd like to update a the TaskState in Tasks table for each id in that idList. This is how my code looks now :

```
using (SqlConnection dataconnection = new SqlConnection(DB))
{
    SqlCommand sqlCommandDelete = new SqlCommand()
    {
        Connection = dataconnection
    };

    dataconnection.Open();

    foreach (var id in idList)
    {
         qlCommandDelete.CommandText = $"UPDATE Tasks SET TaskState = 2 WHERE TaskID = {id}";
         sqlCommandDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that I execute each time the loop fires. Is there maybe a way of connecting all the TaskIDs and executing only once?

Comment: For example, `$"UPDATE ... WHERE TaskID IN ({String.Join(",", idList)})"`

Comment: You can try with TVP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
var ids = idList.Aggregate((x, y) => $"{x}, {y}")
```

Then write sql text as follows

```
qlCommandDelete.CommandText = $"UPDATE Tasks SET TaskState = 2 WHERE TaskID in ({ids})";
```

Comment: +1 assuming TaskId is an Injection safe type like Int. Just use `String.Join` - saves the concatenation problem. There's [ultimately a size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8808935/314291) on the query, though, so batching might still be necessary with a large number of TaskIds. For strings, [parameterization is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/337792/314291)