# Is there a limit to WHERE IN clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Is there a limit to WHERE IN clause in MySQL?

I am talking about that comma delimited string: **41,42,39,40,37,38**

How many ids I can use in that string?

```
DELETE FROM oc_table WHERE id IN (41,42,39,40,37,38)
```

Comment: See the following answer from the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8808935/5389997

Comment: That said, I recommend deleting in smaller batches (no more than 10,000, prefer 1,000). The risk is expanding the rollback segment or causing long-running transactions.